# Converter string ISO-8859-1 para UTF-8 em java

Tags: java, string, utf-8, iso-8859-1

Meu o objetivo é criar uma conversor de `ISO-8859-1` para `UTF-8`.

Já tenho seguinte código:

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException;
import java.nio.charset.Charset;
import org.apache.commons.lang3.StringUtils;

public class Converter {

    public static void main(String... args) throws IOException {

    BufferedReader in = null;
    try {
        File fileDir = new File("Mensagens.java");

        in = new BufferedReader(
           new InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream(fileDir), "ISO-8859-1"));

        String strISO;
        String strUTF8 = null;

        while ((strISO = in.readLine()) != null) {
            byte[] isoBytes = strISO.getBytes("ISO-8859-1");
            String value = new String(isoBytes, "UTF-8"); 
            if(strUTF8 == null ){
                strUTF8 = value;
            }else{
                strUTF8 += value;       
            }   
            System.out.println("ISO : "+strISO);
            System.out.println("UTF : "+value);
        }
        }
        catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e){System.out.println(e.getMessage());}
        catch (IOException e){System.out.println(e.getMessage());}
        catch (Exception e){System.out.println(e.getMessage());}
        finally{
            in.close(); 
        }
        //System.out.println(strUTF8);
    }
}
```

Mas a saida em `UTF-8` não funciona.

Pergunto:

Qual o códio que preciso por em

```
byte[] isoBytes = strISO.getBytes("ISO-8859-1");
String value = new String(isoBytes, "UTF-8"); 
if(strUTF8 == null ){
    strUTF8 = value;
}else{
    strUTF8 += value;       
}   
System.out.println("ISO : "+strISO);
System.out.println("UTF : "+value);
```

para fazer que as duas saidas ISO é UTF sejam iguais?

Saida atual:

```
ISO : "Já existe lançamento com a mesma Nota Fiscal e Fornecedor.";
UTF : "J� existe lan�amento com a mesma Nota Fiscal e Fornecedor.";
```

Saida desejada:

```
ISO : "Já existe lançamento com a mesma Nota Fiscal e Fornecedor.";
UTF : "Já existe lançamento com a mesma Nota Fiscal e Fornecedor.";
```

---

Testes:

```
PrintStream outISO = new PrintStream(System.out, true, "ISO-8859-1");
PrintStream outUTF8 = new PrintStream(System.out, true, "UTF-8");
outISO.println("ISO : " + strISO);
outUTF8.println("UTF : " + value);
ISO : "J� existe lan�amento com a mesma Nota Fiscal e Fornecedor."; 
UTF: "J� existe lan�amento com a mesma Nota Fiscal e Fornecedor.";


PrintStream outISO = new PrintStream(System.out, true, "UTF-8");
PrintStream outUTF8 = new PrintStream(System.out, true, "UTF-8");
outISO.println("ISO : " + strISO);
outUTF8.println("UTF : " + value);
ISO : "Já existe lançamento com a mesma Nota Fiscal e Fornecedor.";
UTF : "J� existe lan�amento com a mesma Nota Fiscal e Fornecedor.";



PrintStream outISO = new PrintStream(System.out, true, "UTF-8");
PrintStream outUTF8 = new PrintStream(System.out, true, "ISO-8859-1");
outISO.println("ISO : " + strISO);
outUTF8.println("UTF : " + value);
ISO : "Já existe lançamento com a mesma Nota Fiscal e Fornecedor.";
UTF : "J? existe lan?amento com a mesma Nota Fiscal e Fornecedor.";



PrintStream outISO = new PrintStream(System.out, true, "ISO-8859-1");
PrintStream outUTF8 = new PrintStream(System.out, true, "ISO-8859-1");
outISO.println("ISO : " + strISO);
outUTF8.println("UTF : " + value);
ISO : "J� existe lan�amento com a mesma Nota Fiscal e Fornecedor.";
UTF : "J? existe lan?amento com a mesma Nota Fiscal e Fornecedor.";
```

Comment: Não seria `System.out.println("UTF : "+strUTF8);`?

Comment: Não porque strUTF8 está incrementanto `strUTF8 += value`. Senão toda vez que imprimisse seria duplicado (com progressão).

Comment: No terminal , não estou usando ide

Comment: A resposta lhe foi útil? Não esqueça de marcar o ✅ para que possa ser utilizada caso alguém tenha uma dúvida similar!

Comment: Mesmo com essas respostas ainda não foi capaz de encontrar um solução.

Answer (score 2):

O problema é que o `System.out.println` mostra apenas em um `encoding`, então para mostrar com `encodings` diferentes você poderia utilizar o `PrintStream`:

```
PrintStream outISO = new PrintStream(System.out, true, "ISO-8859-1");
PrintStream outUTF8 = new PrintStream(System.out, true, "UTF-8");

outISO.println("ISO : " + strISO);
outUTF8.println("UTF : " + value);
```

Ou:

```
System.setOut(new PrintStream(System.out, true, "ISO-8859-1"));
System.out.println("ISO : " + strISO);

System.setOut(new PrintStream(System.out, true, "UTF-8"));
System.out.println("UTF : " + value);
```

Internamente o Java trabalha com `UTF-8` então quando você lê o arquivo você está passando de `ISO-8859-1` para `UTF-8`. Sua variável `strISO` na realidade deveria ser `strUTF8` e sua conversão invertida:

```
byte[] utf8Bytes = strUTF8.getBytes("UTF-8");
String value = new String(utf8Bytes, "ISO-8859-1");
```

Comment: Não deu. As duas saidas :
`ISO : "J� existe lan�amento com a mesma Nota Fiscal e Fornecedor.";`
`UTF: "J� existe lan�amento com a mesma Nota Fiscal e Fornecedor.";`

Comment: @BrunoRozendo eu to achando que a sua variável `strISO` tá em `UTF-8`, tenta imprimir ela no `outUTF8` pra ver o que dá

Comment: Adicionei na resposta os testes

Comment: @BrunoRozendo Beleza, como eu suspeitava, seu arquivo está em `ISO-8859-1` Porém internamente o `Java` trabalha com `UTF-8` então quando você lê o arquivo você está passando de `ISO-8859-1` para `UTF-8`.